# Camel - How do we set a property using producer template?

Tags: apache-camel

Is there a way to set a camel exchange property using the producer template?

Imagine a rest endpoint that receives orders for a customer (not yet in the camel route). Using producer template, I would like to

1. set the customer-id property on the exchange.
2. use it later when required in the route

Yes, I can also use headers and use producerTemplate.sendBodyWithHeaders when using the producer template, but I am thinking of using a property and not a header because thats what property is meant for - meta data inside a route vs headers is more meta data to communicate with external world. Customer-Id has no meaning outside a route for me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To do this, you would set the property on your existing exchange and then pass it to one of the producerTemplate.send() overload methods that accept an Exchange parameter:

```
exchange.setProperty("propertyname", "propertyval");
producerTemplate.send("my-endpoint", exchange);
```

Comment: Thanks. But where would you get the exchange from? Do we just create one? Like "new DefaultExchange(camelContext)"?

Comment: Yes, like new DefaultExchange(camelContext)

Comment: Just wanted to give you a quick heads-up that I added an answer referring to yours. Thank you for your useful pointer!

Answer (score 2):

The [answer](/a/39457716) by [java-addict301](/users/6501190) is helpful, but since it took me some time to figure out how to send an exchange with custom property *and* body, I figured I would share my solution:

```java
producerTemplate.sendBodyAndProperty(myCustomBody, "customer-id", 42);
```

There are a couple of overrides available of the `sendBodyAndProperty` method, a.o. to send to a specific endpoint(URI). And for even more customizability, you could also use:

```java
producerTemplate.send("my-endpoint", exchange -> {
      exchange.setProperty("customer-id", 42);
      exchange.getIn().setBody(myCustomBody);
    });
```

This is based on the implementation of `sendBody` in Camel. Of course, this *(i)* removes the need to create your own `Exchange` and *(ii)* makes it easy to do other custom actions with the exchange, if needed.